# MySQL database population with text file

Tags: mysql

I am following the tutorial here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loading-tables.html

It says to make a file with tab delimited data which I have done and generally looks like this:

`Goofy Kane  Dog   m 1993-06-06 1994-10-10`... The data matches the columns of a table that was created.

When I populate the database by doing this:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/kwal0203/Desktop/wang.txt' INTO TABLE pet;`

I get a database table that has all the fields in the first column and the rest of the columns are `null`.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here I have followed the tutorial exactly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to see the field delimiter `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '` See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Are they really separated by tabs? Is there a chance that your editor is expanding them into spaces?

Comment: What you have posted here does _not_ use tab (real `\t` tabs) delimiters, but rather multi-space delimiters.

Comment: I used the tab key... if that won't get me tabs how do I do it?

Comment: @viraptor how can I find out if that is happening?

Comment: @user2623004 Look through the settings/preference of your editor. There should be an option for it. In case you're using vi(m), that's ":set noet", in case of others, google is your friend.